# why my security strategy works once on 2 calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

I upload file with REST API (with Spring boot and Jhipster), and launch treatment in Async method.

```
@Async("taskExecutor")
public void importArticle(HttpServletRequest request,
                          ImportFichierDTO importFichierDTO,
                          List<Article> articles,
                          Boolean update,
                          Long userId) {
    log.debug("Request to importCompteur pour article");
```

In this treatmen, I need to do data control with connected user (with JWT).

I use this link (https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-rest/src/main/java/org/baeldung/spring/SecurityJavaConfig.java) for configure Strategy

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService, TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
       this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);

}
```

when I call the first time my API, all works. The second time, I have an exception with null data of connected User
The third time, all works, and so on...

There is the stacktrace :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.security.AccessChecker.checkUserAccessToEntityThroughtWebService(AccessChecker.java:59)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.impl.EntiteServiceImpl.checkRightsByEntite(EntiteServiceImpl.java:188)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.impl.EntiteServiceImpl.checkExistAndAccess(EntiteServiceImpl.java:238)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.impl.EntiteServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$24d83d44.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor430.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.impl.EntiteServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8e4bae5.checkExistAndAccess(<generated>)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.impl.ArticleServiceImpl.update(ArticleServiceImpl.java:251)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.impl.ArticleServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ebdd41.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor430.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.impl.ArticleServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$809100fc.update(<generated>)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.thread.ImportFichier.importArticle(ImportFichier.java:539)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.service.thread.ImportFichier$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2f0d691.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at fr.yoni.yvidya.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor430.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

here is the line that triggers the exception :

```
String login = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get();
```

have you an explanation?

Comment: could you please add stacktrace/log when you have the two cases?

Comment: @JonathanJohx I add stacktrace in my post

Answer (score 0):

There were at least 2 bug reports raised for this, before and after your post:

[SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin() with oauth2 does not return the current user](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9613)

[SecurityUtils .getCurrentUserLogin in a microservice returns "null" with OAuth2 and Okta](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10975)

If you still have this issue you could try a work-around to get the user's Authentication:

**SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()**

Have a look at [Baeldung - Retrieve User Information in Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security)

This bad bit of code (no type / null checks) gets all the attributes of the Authentication ie everything in the token:

```
Map<String, Object> attrs = ((OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getAttributes();
```